# How to reshape data wide to long

Tags: sas, transpose

I want to reshape data columns to rows

Initial Table as shown below

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     Name
----------------------------
I001    I002    I003    John
```

Desire Table like

```
ID      Name
------------
I001    John
I002    John
I003    John
```

Can anyone help out?

Thanks lots!!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set up an array of IDs and loop through with an explicit OUTPUT statement.

```
data want;
  set have;

  array ids(3) id1-id3;

  do i=1 to dim(ids);
      ID=ids(i);
      OUTPUT;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PROC TRANSPOSE`  Make sure your data is sorted by `NAME`

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(rename=(_name_=ID));
by Name;
run;
```

Comment: It is worth noting that @Reeza's answer is more efficient.  This way tends to be easier to read for new people looking at your code (and less typing).  Unless your data set is huge, the performance difference will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks both of you. They all work perfectly!! Much appreciated!

Comment: No problems.  Up-votes are always appreciated. ;-)